# Refund with ActiveMerchant (Paypal checkout Express)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant

I'm trying to make refunds using ActiveMerchant gem. After reading the [API](https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant/blob/master/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/paypal/paypal_common_api.rb), I use the refund method like this:
    `response = PaymentGateway.refund(nil,transaction_id)`, where transaction_id is my 17 characters transaction ID. When I execute this code, I've got this error in my logs:

```
    Refund error: transaction 90C30922TK2262948, booking 5569, response= #    
   <ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressResponse:0x00000110a4c048 @params=
   {"timestamp"=>"2013-12-28T11:58:46Z", "ack"=>"Failure", 
   "correlation_id"=>"17b440dc61a09", "version"=>"72", "build"=>"8951431",
   "refund_transaction_id"=>nil, "message"=>"The transaction id is not valid", 
   "error_codes"=>"10004", "Timestamp"=>"2013-12-28T11:58:46Z", "Ack"=>"Failure",
   "CorrelationID"=>"17b440dc61a09", "Errors"=>{"ShortMessage"=>"Transaction refused  
    because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.", 
   "LongMessage"=>"The transaction id is not valid", "ErrorCode"=>"10004", 
   "SeverityCode"=>"Error"}, "Version"=>"72", "Build"=>"8951431", 
   "RefundTransactionID"=>nil}
```

The id parameter doesn't seem to be accepted by the Paypal API.
I'm using the *transfer* method, but I'd rather use the *refund* one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [paypal_api](https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant/blob/master/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/paypal/paypal_common_api.rb)

This is what your refund should look like

```
  # Refunds a transaction.
  #
  # For a full refund pass nil for the amount:
  #
  # gateway.refund nil, 'G39883289DH238'
  #
  # This will automatically make the :refund_type be "Full".
  #
  # For a partial refund just pass the amount as usual:
  #
  # gateway.refund 100, 'UBU83983N920'
  #
  def refund(money, identification, options = {})
    commit 'RefundTransaction', build_refund_request(money, identification, options)
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

make sure that you use the transaction id when the amount was 'capture'. in my app, i use authorize/capture/refund API. the transaction id when i 'authorize' is different from the transaction id when i 'capture'

here's the data i got when i capture the amount.

```
timestamp: '2014-01-30T21:59:33Z'
ack: Success
correlation_id: 7803f5d114c45
version: '72'
build: '9285531'
authorization_id: 04G82796YE043610H
transaction_id: 9A656277C6136044L
parent_transaction_id: 04G82796YE043610H
receipt_id:
transaction_type: express-checkout
payment_type: instant
payment_date: '2014-01-30T21:59:32Z'
gross_amount: '15.97'
gross_amount_currency_id: USD
fee_amount: '0.76'
fee_amount_currency_id: USD
tax_amount: '0.00'
tax_amount_currency_id: USD
exchange_rate:
payment_status: Completed
pending_reason: none
reason_code: none
protection_eligibility: Eligible
protection_eligibility_type: ItemNotReceivedEligible,UnauthorizedPaymentEligible
AuthorizationID: 04G82796YE043610H
PaymentInfo:
  TransactionID: 9A656277C6136044L
  ParentTransactionID: 04G82796YE043610H
  ReceiptID:
  TransactionType: express-checkout
  PaymentType: instant
  PaymentDate: '2014-01-30T21:59:32Z'
  GrossAmount: '15.97'
  FeeAmount: '0.76'
  TaxAmount: '0.00'
  ExchangeRate:
  PaymentStatus: Completed
  PendingReason: none
  ReasonCode: none
  ProtectionEligibility: Eligible
  ProtectionEligibilityType: ItemNotReceivedEligible,UnauthorizedPaymentEligible
```

then i call the refund method:

```
Gateway.refund(798,'9A656277C6136044L')

=> #<ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressResponse:0x007ff4e744b450
 @authorization="70L01419MK614945K",
 @avs_result=
  {"code"=>nil, "message"=>nil, "street_match"=>nil, "postal_match"=>nil},
 @cvv_result={"code"=>nil, "message"=>nil},
 @fraud_review=false,
 @message="Success",
 @params=
  {"timestamp"=>"2014-01-31T01:56:47Z",
   "ack"=>"Success",
   "correlation_id"=>"55810b5eb3c3d",
   "version"=>"72",
   "build"=>"9285531",
   "refund_transaction_id"=>"70L01419MK614945K",
   "net_refund_amount"=>"7.75",
   "net_refund_amount_currency_id"=>"USD",
   "fee_refund_amount"=>"0.23",
   "fee_refund_amount_currency_id"=>"USD",
   "gross_refund_amount"=>"7.98",
   "gross_refund_amount_currency_id"=>"USD",
   "total_refunded_amount"=>"7.98",
   "total_refunded_amount_currency_id"=>"USD",
   "Timestamp"=>"2014-01-31T01:56:47Z",
   "Ack"=>"Success",
   "CorrelationID"=>"55810b5eb3c3d",
   "Version"=>"72",
   "Build"=>"9285531",
   "RefundTransactionID"=>"70L01419MK614945K",
   "NetRefundAmount"=>"7.75",
   "FeeRefundAmount"=>"0.23",
   "GrossRefundAmount"=>"7.98",
   "TotalRefundedAmount"=>"7.98"},
 @success=true,
 @test=true>
```

hth